# Hibernate search manual indexing

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm new to Hibernate Search.  I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search to search for addresses.  I'm using Hibernate Search 5.5.6.Final.  My addresses table has >15 million records.  I use manual indexing to create lucene index for the existing addresses table.  The indexing completes but when I browse them via Luke, it has less than 70,000 documents.  Does this seem right? Shouldn't the document number be a lot more than the number of records? Is there a way to ensure that the indexing ran through all records? please help...

Here's my entiy:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "ADDRESSES_LOOKUP")
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customanalyzer",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                @TokenFilterDef(factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class, params = {
                        @Parameter(name = "language", value = "English")
                })
        })
@Indexed
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private String id;

    @Column (name = "BUILDING_NAME")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String buildingName;

    @Column (name = "FLAT_NUMBER")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String flatNumber;

    @Column (name = "FLAT_TYPE")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String flatType;

    @Column (name = "LEVEL_NUMBER")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String levelNumber;

    @Column (name = "LEVEL_TYPE")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String levelType;

    @Column (name = "NUMBER_FIRST")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String numberFirst;

    @Column (name = "NUMBER_LAST")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String numberLast;

    @Column (name = "STREET_NAME")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String streetName;

    @Column (name = "STREET_TYPE_CODE")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String streetType;

    @Column (name = "LOCALITY_NAME")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String locality;

    @Column (name = "STATE_ABBREVIATION")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String state;

    @Column (name = "POSTCODE")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String postcode;

    @Column (name = "ADDRESS")
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer")
    private String address;
```

Here's the code for indexing

```
public void initializeHibernateSearch() {
    logger.info("Start initialising hibernate search index.");
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        fullTextEntityManager
                .createIndexer()
                .typesToIndexInParallel( 3 )
                .batchSizeToLoadObjects( 50 )
                .cacheMode( CacheMode.IGNORE )
                .threadsToLoadObjects( 30 )
                .idFetchSize( 150 )
                .transactionTimeout( 1800 )
                .startAndWait();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("HIBERNATE SEARCH INDEX INITIALISED.");
}
```

Comment: The code looks right. No exceptions at all?

Comment: No exception.  Now I'm trying to run lucene index independently from hibernate search and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to use a ProgressMonitor (either the SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor or a custom one that you define) and step into a few of the methods available, like `addToTotalCount` which should tell you how many addresses it intends to index.  There's also a `printStatusMessage` method that should give you some progress visibility.

```
SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor();
fullTextSession
                .createIndexer(Address.class)
                .typesToIndexInParallel(1)
                .batchSizeToLoadObjects(50)
                .cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
                .threadsToLoadObjects(30)
                .idFetchSize(150)
                .progressMonitor(progressMonitor)
                .startAndWait();
```

Are there any other columns in that table?  I'm wondering if you only have 70,000 that actually have data in those indexes columns.